# Mark of the Web breaking locally hosted page with video tag

Tags: internet-explorer, video

I've made a video presentation tool using Video.js, which is in the final stages of testing. The tool will be hosted locally, and I'm encountering the IE warning "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls".

Obviously the solution would be to add a mark of the web with the proper windows line breaks and encoded in UTF-8.

Not only does the error still occur, but with MOTW applied, clicking "Allow blocked content" does not remove the error. Instead the error will constantly instantly reappear.

- Without MOTW clicking the warning leads to the page loading correctly with full functionality.
- With the video tag removed and all javascript links and scripts in place, MOTW works and removed the IE warning.

The following MCVE that recreates the issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
    <body>
        <video>
            <source src="video/TestVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            <source src="video/TestVideo.webm" type='video/webm' />
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm stumped. Very unusual. What do you think? I'm testing in IE11/Win7.

Edit: I've researched this and tested it plenty. Adding the mark of the web only makes the issue worse.

The tool is going to be kept on usb sticks for presentation purposes, so it needs to work on any machine without going into IE settings. Of course, it is just one click of a button… but presentation is everything !

Comment: @timothyclifford Specifically not a duplicate of the question – one answer to that question is to use the MOTW as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=VS.85).aspx, this question is about why that approach is failing in this case.

Comment: Noted, removed comments